# Graphing relationships question from Khan Academy

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Bob has budgeted $5000$ dollars for home renovations. Cement costs $10$ cents per kilogram , and a $10$ centimeter thick board of lumber costs $3$ dollars per square meter.
To determine how to spend his budget, Bob graphs the amount of cement he can buy (in kilograms) as a function of the amount of lumber he buys (in square meters).

Which axis should represent the amount of cement?

Potentially, mathematical variables can have any value, but the variables under discussion here are bounded by the real-world context they model.

What is the range of valid values for the amount of cement?

What I have gotten out of this:

I know that the independent variable is typically plotted on the horizontal axis and it seems that the amount of Cement is a function of the amount of lumber so, I went ahead and said that the amount of Cement should be on the vertical axis.

Now finding the range of valid values for the amount of cement is where I feel completely clueless. I have no idea how to set up an equation to solve for the max value. It seems that the minimum value would be $0$ though.

Comment: I think it will be a straight line in the first quadrant touching both the axis, the equation of the line is $0.001*x_1+3*x_2=5000$, here $x_1$ is the amount of cement in kg. and $x_2$ is the lumber in $m^2$

Comment: But then what are the values for the amount of cement?

Comment: the more cement he buys the less lumber he can buy, many values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ will satisfy the above equation

Comment: in theory the straight line should form a triangle with the X and Y axis, but because of the unit conversion of 0.10 cents to dollars the actual graph is almost a vertical straight line, same equation can be written as $y=\frac{5000-3x}{0.001}$

Comment: Do you really mean $.10$ cents per kg, or do you mean $10$ cents per kilogram ($\$.10$ per kilogram)?

Comment: @paw88789 Sorry. Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the extremes:

Bob could use the entire budget to buy lumber (amount of cement would be $0$ in this case); or he could spend all the money on cement (no lumber), $5000/0.1=50000$ kg of cement.  So the possible range of values for cement is $0$ to $50,000$ kg.